# How do I authenticate with an API using Digest authentication?

Tags: c#, digest-authentication

I'm new to the areas of API's, but I need to integrate with an API that is using Digest Auth.

I have a username and password which has been provided but what format should this be sent in?

I'm confused as to why I can't find this anywhere on the internet... If anyone can provide some generic example client code in c# that would also be incredibly useful.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxhw3bcy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thats great thanks. Out of interest though what does the request actually look like with the credentials? What does the new NetworkCredentials(user, Pass) actually end up passing?